# How to record audio only if it is above certain sound level?

Tags: android, audio-recording

I was trying to do a voice capturing app that only capture when there is noise.
So I used the getMaxAmplitude() method from Media Recorder class.
And here is my idea and work:
I started a **service** that used a MediaRecorder object to record the sound from emulator' mic, then I have a thread running to check the getMaxAmplitude() value from that object, if it goes above a particular level, I start another recording using a new object from MediaRecorder for a period of time and then save it. If there are for example "3 noises" after starting the service of my app, it should then save 4 audio files, including the main one that use to monitor the amplitude level.

BUT I notice a problem, that is the microphone of android only allows 1 media recorder at a time. 
So is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Could you kill the first recording and then start the new one? Just an idea...

Comment: Doing this will result my app only record once. Imagine if you need to record sequence of noises, killing the main one will stop the monitor service after recording the first noise

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can't be done that way, as you said, only one component can access certain hardware at a time. You'll probably have to make your own recorder, where it's constantly recording and checking, and then manually saving the data above your threshold directly from what's being actively recording.

Comment: Maybe you could store the times when the volume goes over the level and just parse out the part of the audio you want? Or only play that part of it based on your array of volume change events? Hope this helps!

Comment: You'll soon discover that "a particular sound level" is a very poor way to trigger recording.  But that's a lesson to be learned, in time.

Comment: when the trigger goes off, start recording.  When the amplitude goes below your desired level, start a `Timer`.  If a certain amount of time elapses, save your recording and wait for your amplitude to go breach the lower limit again.

Answer (score 0):

You might note the timestamps for the start and end of the noises, and then pull out the needed sections from the audio file at a later time.

Of course, this may not fit exactly with what you're trying to do... tough to say at this point.